# SSH::channel hang on 'select'?

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am learning how to use Net::SSH to manipulate the file transfer between two remote machines. The task is simple: on machine A there is "some.tar.gz" file which I need to transfer to machine B and unzip.

Here is my starting code, which hangs. And if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, it reports:

```
net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:30:in `select': Interrupt.
```

So I guess it hangs on select.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start("ipB", "user1", :password => "pwd1") do |ssh1|
  Net::SSH.start("ipA", "user2", :password => "pwd2") do |ssh2|
    ssh2.exec "cat /home/user2/some.tar.gz" do |ch, stream, data|
      #puts data
      ssh1.exec("tar zxvf -")
      ssh1.send_data data
      ssh1.eof!
    end
    ssh2.loop
  end
  ssh1.loop
end
```

Thanks a lot for the help.